# Filtering on proxyAddresses with Microsoft Graph API that endsWith or contains a string

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I need to find users and groups with a proxyAddress that endsWith a specific string, e.g. `@acme.com`.

I can do startsWith:

```
$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:startswith(x,'smtp:johndoe'))
```

Or equals:

```
$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'smtp:johndoe@acme.com')
```

But endsWith, contains, like don't seem to work:

```
$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:contains(x,'@acme.com'))
```

and results in a BadRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph endpoints don't support `endsWith` and there is a limited number of endpoints that support `contains`. In this case, `contains` isn't supported by Azure AD entities. From the [documentation on $filter](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter):

> **Note:** The following `$filter` operators are not supported for Azure AD resources:  `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`. The `contains` string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

As an aside, the syntax you used for `contains` is also a bit off. The correct syntax would be `contains({property},'{subString}')`. It is similar to `startsWith` and doesn't require/support wildcards.

Comment: Thanks Marc! Do you know are there plans to enable support of endsWith or contains?  For robust searching it seems pretty limited currently.

Comment: I've not heard anything regarding `endsWith` but I know there has been a lot of developer interest in supporting `contains`. It isn't trivial to implement however so I wouldn't want to guess at an ETA for it.

Comment: Michael, please file a request for endsWith or contains on UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: Thanks Dan!  I posted this idea:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31838047-allow-ms-graph-proxyaddress-filters-to-specify-end